# Call chaining in golang templates

Tags: templates, go

Suppose you have the following code

```
router.Get("foo").URL("id", id)
```

If I want to do something similar in a go template. I believe I have to go the long way and create an intermediary variable.

```
{{ $urlGenerator := .Router.Get "foo" }}
{{ $urlGenerator.URL "id" .Id }}
```

Preferably it would look like something like this

```
{{ (.Router.Get "foo") .Url }}
```

Or simply

```
{{ .Router.Get("foo").Url }}
```

Has anyone found a way that works a little like this? I can not find anything in the documentation regarding this, other than pipes, which works as... pipes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's in the very end of the [`Arguments`](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Arguments) paragraph of the `text/template` package doc:

> - A parenthesized instance of one the above, for grouping. The result may be accessed by a field or map key invocation:
>
>   - `print (.F1 arg1) (.F2 arg2)`
>   - `(.StructValuedMethod "arg").Field`

Comment: Ah I nearly had it... It would appear my eyes simply glossed over in the end, I could've sworn I read that section in entirety 5 times